# Vimperator: Map key to get out of Hints-mode

Tags: browser-addons, vimperator

When I enter `f` in Vimperator I see all the links I could jump to. I want to exit this mode (Hints mode), with a key other than `<Esc>`.

Currently: `<Esc>` will exit, I'd like to map `\` instead.

I'd like to map like: `:map \\` to `<Esc>`

I've looked through the docs on `<Esc>` and `hints mode`, can `<Esc>` be remapped?

Comment: Hi, are you sure \ is a good key ? It will prevent you from writing it in insert mode.

Comment: It's what i've used for years in vim as my <Leader>. I use <C-\> for '\' in insert mode.